# Confused about $\csc(x)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The title says it all, let's take this simple example:

[image: Figure 1]

I want to find $c$.

Using $\sin$ I get:

1. $\sin(30)$ = $4 / c$
2. $c = 4 / \sin(30) = 8$

Now, using $\csc$:

1. $\csc(30) = c / 4$
2. $c = \csc(30) * 4 = 8$

But also:

1. $\csc(30) = c / 4$
2. $\tan(30) = 4 / a$
3. $4 = \tan(30) * a$
4. $c = \csc(30)\cdot \tan(30)\cdot c = c\cdot (c / 4)\cdot (4 / a) = c$
5. OR: $\csc(30) \cdot \tan(30)\cdot c = \sec(30)\cdot  c \approx c$

What's gone wrong here, I assumed $c$ would cancel out?

EDIT 1: Why isn't $c$ cancelling out in the last example, even after the fix?

EDIT 2: Fixed steps 2 and 3 (changed $c$ to $a$). Thank you for your help, silly mistakes.

Comment: Item $2$ is the error. $\tan 30=\frac4a$ is what it should be.

Comment: @MattSamuel thank you, been a long night :)!

Comment: My advice is too never use $\sec$ or $\operatorname{cosec}$. And if you are imposed to work with them, translate a soon as possible to $\sin,\cos$.

Comment: @zwim, thanks for the advice, I just got a bit OCD over this as it didn't add up (well still doesn't).

Comment: @zwim I think this advice is a bit extreme. While I see where you're coming from, they have a name for a reason. For instance, $1+\tan^2 x=\sec^2 x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$\tan(30°)=\frac{4}{a}\text{ which isn't } \frac{4}{c}$$

Now we have that $$c=\text{cosec}(30°)·4\;\text{ and } \;4=\tan(30)°·a$$
Thus $$c=\text{cosec}(30°)·\tan(30°)·a=\frac{c}{4}·\frac{4}{a}·a\not= \frac{c}{4}·\frac{4}{a}·\color{red}{c}$$ as pointed out in the comments

Comment: Thank you for spotting this, got it!

Comment: No problem! @Shibalicious

Comment: So now I got sec(30) * c, which is c ~= 9.23, why?

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean by 'I got $\sec(30°)·c$, which is $c=9.23$'?

Comment: c = (c / 4) * (4 / a) * c = sec(30) * c ~= 9.23

Comment: I've edited the answer

Comment: Spot on, I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec30^{\circ}=\frac{1}{\cos30^{\circ}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: This is a non sequitur.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva It's just a post of an arbitrary fact. What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @Matt Samuel I wrote where was a mistake. See please better. It's exactly, that you wrote.

Comment: The only place I see $\sec 30$ is already well after the first error. It's true that it's an error thinking it's equal to $1$, but that's not the important error.